# A question on differentiability and boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f:R\to R$ be a differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=1$. Show that $f$ is unbounded.

Here is my try

For $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $M$ in reals such that

$|f'(x)-1|<\epsilon$ whenever $x>M$

In particular, suppose $\epsilon=1/2$

Then for $x>M$, we have  $f'(x)>1/2$

The function is increasing after a certain point. Thus, it is unbounded above.

Is this the right approach.

My answer didn't convince me. I'm pretty sure there are better ways. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the best way (except that "increasing" does not imply "unbounded", hence you have to modify this step). Additionally, this was asked several times on the site.

Comment: @Did : i am not able to find the question. Would you please help me with the final step?

Comment: Use the Mean Value Theorem to conclude that if $x\gt M$ then $f(x)\gt f(M)+(1/2)(x-M)$.

Comment: Haha..that was simple. Thanks!

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Would you please post this as an asnwer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M\gt 0$ be given. We want to show that there exists a $B$ such that if $x\gt B$, then $f(x)\gt M$.

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=1$, there exists a real number $A$ such that $f'(x)\gt \frac{1}{2}$ if $x\gt A$.

Use the Mean Value Theorem to conclude that if $x>A$ then 
$$f(x)>f(A)+\frac{1}{2}(x−A).\tag{1}$$
Now use Inequality (1) to show that if 
$$B=\max(A, 2M+A-2f(A))$$
and $x\gt B$  then $f(x)\gt M$.

**Remark:** We used a formal style that may hide the geometric simplicity of the idea. From Inequality (1), after a while, each time we increment $x$ by $1$, $f(x)$ is incremented by at least $\frac{1}{2}$, so must blow up. In fact because after a while we also have $f'(x)\lt \frac{3}{2}$, the blowup is quite sedate.